# Is it possible to avoid keeping a reference to the listeners?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to create a "passive view" idea where user actions fire the listener but application it self does not.

Consider a case where I need to listen for ComponentResized events. When the user resizes the window I do something. But one button press calls `setSize()` method of this component as well. When the `setSize` is called from the program, I do not want the listener to be fired. But when it comes from user action I want.

```
public class Example extends JFrame {
    static boolean stopResizing = false;

    public Example() {
        super("");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        ComponentAdapter listener = new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                if (stopResizing == true)
                    return;
                System.out.println("RESIZED");
            }
        };
        addComponentListener(listener);

        JButton changeSizeButton = new JButton("Change size");
        changeSizeButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            stopResizing = true;
            setSize(getSize().width + 15, getSize().height);
            stopResizing = false;
        });

        add(changeSizeButton);
        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Example().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

}
```

In the example above, when the window gets resized, "resized" is printed. But when the button is pressed, it is printed as well. I know that I can `remove` and re-`add` the component listener, but can this be avoided? In "big" views where multiple listeners are registered, this will be pain.

As I can see by following the call hierarchy of `setSize`, the event is posted in the `EventQueue`. That's why the boolean flag does not work. The flag becomes `true` before the event is fired. So, maybe the question can be derived to "can I manipulate (how safe/trust-able could that be) the EventQueue?". Manipulating it, by adding the `stopResizing = false` before the fire event is posted.

Another option maybe is to create a static method that iterates all listeners, removes them, runs a `Runnable` (containing the `setSize`) and then the method adds them back on. But as far as I know, removing all listeners from a component brutally, will remove Swing's internal listeners as well and components will have unexpected behavior. Maybe there is a way to separate the custom (added by me) listeners from Swing's without keeping references?

I tried to add the `stopResizing = false` into a `invokeLater` call, but it does not work either.

Keep in mind this is not about ComponentListeners only. It is for any kind of listeners, for any kind of components. Thus, I want to it to "generalize" it.

**UPDATE**
Even if I remove the listener, the "resized" is printed.

```
public class Example extends JFrame {

    public Example() {
        super("");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        ComponentAdapter listener = new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                System.out.println("RESIZED");
            }
        };

        addComponentListener(listener);

        JButton changeSizeButton = new JButton("Change size");
        changeSizeButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            removeComponentListener(listener);
            setSize(getSize().width + 15, getSize().height);
            addComponentListener(listener);
        });

        add(changeSizeButton);
        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Example().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

}
```

The reason I want to avoid invokeLater is because the code could implicitly look like:

```
    removeComponentListener(listener);
    setSize(getSize().width + 15, getSize().height); //I dont want to fire the listener
    addComponentListener(listener);
    setSize(getSize().width + 15, getSize().height); // I Want to fire the listener
```

Comment: hi perhaps move the code to clear the `stopResizing` flag to one of the resize event handlers (you might need to make it `AtomicBoolean` or `volatile` for thread visibility).

Comment: @IronMan The problem is not thread visibility. The problem is that the event is fired after the `stopResizing = false`. With other words, the code in `ActionListener` is "`stopResizing = true; stopResizing=false; fireEvent()`.

Comment: *Even if I remove the listener, the "resized" is printed.* - this would indicate that code in the setSize(...) method is adding the ComponentEvent to the end of the EDT, so it is handled after you add the listener back to the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending 2 days reading multiple times EventQueue class, I think I solved it. The solution seems to be a [SecondaryLoop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SecondaryLoop.html) while a background thread waits until all events are dispatched (that includes the component event in our case).

```
public class Example extends JFrame {

    public Example() {
        super("");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        ComponentAdapter listener = new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                System.out.println("RESIZED");
            }
        };

        addComponentListener(listener);

        JButton changeSizeButton = new JButton("Change size");
        changeSizeButton.addActionListener(e -> {

            removeComponentListener(listener);
            setSize(new Dimension(getSize().width + 1, getSize().height));
            waitUntilAllEventsAreDispatched();
            addComponentListener(listener);

            setSize(new Dimension(getSize().width + 1, getSize().height)); //I want here to print
        });

        add(changeSizeButton);
        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
    }

    private EventQueue eventQueue() {
        return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue();
    }

    private void waitUntilAllEventsAreDispatched() {
        SecondaryLoop secondaryLoop = eventQueue().createSecondaryLoop();
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (eventQueue().peekEvent() != null)
                ;
            secondaryLoop.exit();
        }).start();
        secondaryLoop.enter();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Example().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

}
```

This example will print "RESIZED" only one time.

It also works with a boolean flag, as expected:

```
ComponentAdapter listener = new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        if (allListenersDisabled)
            return;
        System.out.println("RESIZED");
    }
};

addComponentListener(listener);

JButton changeSizeButton = new JButton("Change size");
changeSizeButton.addActionListener(e -> {

    allListenersDisabled = true;
    setSize(new Dimension(getSize().width + 1, getSize().height));
    waitUntilAllEventsAreDispatched();
    allListenersDisabled = false;

    setSize(new Dimension(getSize().width + 1, getSize().height)); //I want here to print
});
```

Comment: Interesting. The `SecondaryLoop` is new to me. I tried  to do something similar without  `SecondaryLoop` but i did not finish it. Maybe I'll find time to get back to it. Side note `EventQueue eventQueue =...` is not used.

Comment: @c0der I did not know about secondary loop either. I tried it and it worked. About unused variable, I just forgot it there. :)

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to add the stopResizing = false into a invokeLater call, but it does not work either.

It does work. I do not know how did you try, but this works:

```java
        changeSizeButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            stopResizing = true;
            setSize(getSize().width + 15, getSize().height);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                stopResizing = false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: It does work. Not robust though. I would prefer to implement it like [so](https://repl.it/@c0derrepo/SwingFireSilentAction#Main.java)

Comment: I tried the exact same thing, but since the real application does not use a boolean value, I did not try it with a flag. It actually seem to work. I will try to investigate more on it and I will let you know. Weird thing though.

Comment: I updated my answer. Even with removing the listener, I get the same result. @c0der in case you are interested.

Comment: _Even with removing the listener, I get the same result_ it is not surprising because it still suffers from timing problem. You can by pass it as in the link I posted but it is not elegant.

Comment: @c0der I think I have found the solution. If you want, take a look. Thank you both for your time.

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to remove the event listener before calling `setSize()`. Then add it back after.